# What are the options for RUBYOPT env?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-6, ruby-2.7

All I could find out is `-W:no-deprecated` & `-W:no-experimental` flags.

I have tried to understand through `RUBYOPT`'s [spec](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/c5eb24349a4535948514fe765c3ddb0628d81004/spec/ruby/command_line/rubyopt_spec.rb) but got lost. Are there any other options available for the `RUBYOPT` env?

Comment: If anyone interested, there seems to be a list of [compatible gems](https://prathamesh.tech/ruby-2-7-compatible-gems/) for Ruby 2.7 by [Prathamesh Sonpatki](https://twitter.com/_cha1tanya).

Answer (score 2):

Check the Ruby manpage (run `man ruby`).

```
RUBYOPT    Additional Ruby options.

  e.g. RUBYOPT="-w -Ke"

  Note that RUBYOPT can contain only -d, -E, -I, -K, -r, -T, -U, -v, -w, -W, --debug, --disable-FEATURE and --enable-FEATURE.
```

The meaning of the individual flags are explained in the manpage itself.